# Comparing 2d string array to a string C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a 2d string array and a string that I would like to compare but strcmp does not work unless I cast the string to a (const char*) and this leads me with a seg fault.

Currently my code is simplified as:

```
string dog;

cin >> dog;

string cat[10][10];

//The cat array is then filled with values through cin

//This is the troublesome part 

if (strcmp(cat[4][3].c_str(), dog[0]) == 0) {
//do stuff
}
```

Obtaining the address of dog with &dog[0] works, but then I get the whole word that was put into dog instead of just the letter I want.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Here's [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Enjoy.

Comment: If you only want to compare the first character, you don't need `strcmp`.  If you want to see if that single character is somewhere in the other string, use `string::find`.

Answer (score 0):

> string cat[10][10];
>
> //The cat array is then filled with values through cin
>
> //This is the troublesome part
>
> ```
> if (strcmp(cat[4][3].c_str(), dog[0]) == 0) {
> //do stuff
> }
> ```

This is what I think is happening. You want to create a string cat[10], and not string cat[10][10]

Let me explain it now.
`//cat[0] =` this doesn't take a "string", it takes an array of 10 strings [not a string of 10 characters which i think is what u expect)

```
cat[0][0] = "hello world";
//to access "h" letter you would need to use
cat[0][0][0] and then do

if (cat[0][0][0] != dog[0])
```

which i think is what u wanna do (compare a letter) otherwise to compare the strings just

```
if (cat[0][0] != dog) //note that this is a case sensitive
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working with C++ `std::string` which has an overloaded `operator==`, so you don't really need `strcmp` at all.  If you want to see if two `string`s are equal, you can just do `cat[4][3] == dog`.  `cat[4][3]` is a `std::string`, so you can just compare it to `dog` directly.

If you just want to compare the first character though, you can do `cat[4][3][0] == dog[0]`.